# Fonts in Flutter web does not work as expected

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, font-family

As default the flutter web should support the fonts specified in pubspec.yaml.. But the fonts work perfectly fine for andriod mobile application but in web the font looks different.. sans-serif font is default font in flutter web even if i have specified other type in my ThemeData..
If some one can provide latest guidelines to add font in flutter web it will be helpful.. Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you have checked the usual culprits - whether the fonts have been properly registered in `pubspec.yaml` and are accessible in runtime? Also, if it's applicable to your usecase you can take a look at https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts it'd simplify loading and changing fonts a lot.

Comment: Google fonts -> https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts  worked for me perfectly - Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had like this issue and fixed with below commands

flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit

flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit

you can see below link for better understand

[enter link description here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/web-renderers)